# Azure Function Blob Storage Trigger is not triggering

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I tested the blob storage trigger in my local in vs code. I'm using python and it is working but when I pushed the code to Azure and tried to store the file but nothing showing in the log. I waited for like 15-30 mins and still nothing. How do I know it is running or not? Please help!

Comment: 1, local.settings.json will not upload when deploy to azure. 2, You can go to kudu to see your log:  Go to `https://yourfunctionappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`,  then LogFiles -> Application -> Functions -> Function -> yourtriggername.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bowman said, maybe the problem is the storage connections in local.settings.json, you should navigate to **configuration** under **settings** to check the **app settings** with a storage connection string value like the picture below.

[image]

And if you want to see the details in logs, you can go to **KUDU** unless you use **Consumption plan**, because Advanced Tools (Kudu) is currently not supported for Linux Consumption plans.
[image]

Another way is adding an **output binding**, like creating a new blob after triggering. If your function run successfully, there should be a new blob in your container. If the new blob is not created, you can check your code or anything wrong else.

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func


def main(queuemsg: func.QueueMessage, inputblob: func.InputStream,
         outputblob: func.Out[func.InputStream]):
    logging.info('Python Queue trigger function processed %s', inputblob.name)
    outputblob.set(inputblob)
```

Refer to the docs to add output binding if you need: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-output?tabs=python